# CSS3 Second 3D Perspective

Tags: css, 3d, perspective

Hello guys I have a map like this http://sinanisler.com/demo/map/

and as you can see there is some trees but not true perspective ı want this http://sinanisler.com/demo/musteri/uploads/res.png
Question is clear how can I do trees like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Apply this style to the main div container to preserve 3d drawing of the children:

```
[-webkit-/-moz-/...]transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

**2)** Apply a rotation to the trees:

```
[-webkit-/-moz-/...]transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0,-90deg);
```

**3)** Use a transparent background image for the trees

Comment: http://sinanisler.com/demo/map/ its working but not all 3D. Only first one working.

Comment: @sinanisler Hmmm... image div containers are missing `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. And, where is the `agac` CCS class defined?

Comment: Juan I'm working on this thing but not exactly working. Your solution true but in this case :D really different things happening. Thanks for answer. if I will fix all things I'll share here.